# Periodic motion on a torus and Lyusternik-Fet Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

I recently came across the Lyusternik-Fet theorem concerning closed geodesics on a compact manifold.

For simplicity of description, take the 2-torus, and imagine it represents the configuration space of a double pendulum.
For every pair of integers $m,n$ (where $m$ represents the number of rotations done by the fist link and $n$ by the second), there exist a periodic motion that on such torus traces a closed geodesic.

A way in which the Theorem is presented is, e.g.:

> For energy $E > max(U)$ and $(m, n) ∈ \mathbb Z^2$, there exists a
>   periodic motion with this total energy for which the first segment of
>   the double pendulum rotates $m$ times and the second $n$ times.

Which to me sounds like that *for every* value of the total energy $E$ (provided it's just bigger than the maximal value of the potential energy $U$) I could get a periodic motion *with arbitrary* $m$ and $n$, which seems absurd.

What I haven't understood?

Comment: Consider a very simplified variant, two discs rotating horizontally , one with its axis fixed to the ground and the other with its axis attached  to the first at some distance from the center. It's easy to see that Ideally with a little amount of energy you can accomplish the conditions of the theorem. For one make m revolutions when the other makes n requires an adjustment of the amount of energy of one disc **relatively** to the other. The discs can go as slow as necessary.

Comment: That's a very interesting comment, thank you! Anyway, does that mean that for _every_ value of the energy I would get infinitely many homotopycally different periodic trajectories? And doesn't the potential of the double pendulum depend on the angular frequencies, i.e. $U=\sum_i \omega_i^2 x_i^2 /2$?

Comment: For little amplitudes yes, but the double pendulum with such an amount of energy is very far from that

Comment: I don't want to bother you, but could I ask you to reformulate your last assertion?

Comment: The system [has not any characteristic frequency](https://youtu.be/d2E5oojoXjk?t=181)